# Groovy Meta Programming with getter method

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

Would someone help me figure out why this added "get" method works with one class(String) but not the other class(Node)?

```
String.metaClass.getFoo = { "string foo" }
s = "test"
println s.foo // WORKS: get "string foo"

Node.metaClass.getFoo = { "node foo" }
xml = "<test><body>test</body></test>"
nodes = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
println nodes.foo // NOT WORK: gets []
```

How do I make calling the "foo" resulting the same as getFoo() for class Node?

Comment: The same result is noticed in both cases that you mentioned. Tried it [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5113343920570368).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodes.foo` will try to find an element in the parsed tree of nodes. Directly using `getFoo()` would be the only option AFAIK.

Comment: Never thought of this. But this makes sense.  So I assume the propertyMissing() taking priority over the getter/setter.